# SQL to JSON Conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, json

I have an SQL Data and I'm planning to convert this to JSOn and then upload it in Firebase Database. I have exported my table on HeidiSQL and the used an online tool to convert my table. But a syntax error near "max" was showing and I can't understand why. The only max value that I have in my SQL file is like this

```
"content" NVARCHAR(max) NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

Can someone please explain to me what is this all about?

Comment: can you post the rest of the relevant query?

Comment: If you are using phpmyadmin you can simply export the data as json format.OR http://www.joe0.com/2016/02/04/export-a-mysql-database-in-json-format-using-heidisql/

Comment: @Priyank I'm using HeidiSql

Comment: I suspect `nvarchar(max)` is a SQL Server specific thing.

Comment: @bleykFaust Have you check this link http://www.joe0.com/2016/02/04/export-a-mysql-database-in-json-format-using-heidisql/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name where using MSSql but where accessing it using HeidiSql